# Returning contentful Date & Time as a string not number

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5, blogs, contentful

I am trying to add the blog created time to my blog using contentful and angular 5. I have got the date returning using:

```
<p> Published: {{blog.fields.createdAt}}</p>
```

however this returns it like:

```
Published: 2018-05-17
```

Where as I would like it to return like:

```
17th May 2018
```

The settings on the date and time feature within contentful do not have an option for string formatting. Is there anything I can do in angular that would make this change for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

You can use the angular date pipe.

```
<p> Published: {{blog.fields.createdAt | date:'dd LLL yyyy'}}</p>
```

Can't check but that should do it.

Worth noting that Angular doesn't have a format option for the ordinal (th, nd). You would have to implement something to do that. Possibly creating a custom pipe that implements the DatePipe.